# django rest framework access item by lookup field instead of pk 3.4 DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to have lookup field in order my frontend sends email which should be deleted but I get item not found. I've researched a lot about this problem but I can't figure out which DRF version what supports.

```
class EmailReminderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='web:email_reminder-detail',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = EmailReminder
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'email'}
        }
```

Now I have url but it points to instance pk, not by my desired lookup field.
Any suggestions of how it works in 3.4 version or do you have any other solutions to some lower version >=3.0?

Answer (score 9):

Oh okay, I got it. For serialized models you only need lookup_field in your view but for hyperlinked serialized models you need extra_kwargs in serializers plus lookup field in views. Hope it helps someone

Comment: Well it doesn't help much.. what do we put in the `extra_kwargs`?

Comment: [This DRF Doc section](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined) might bring a little light into the dark

Answer (score 8):

You should modify the lookup field in your view instead. As shown in [DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview), you can do the following.

in `views.py`

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class EmailReminderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TagSerializer
    lookup_field = 'email'
```

Comment: I think i've tryed almost every combination with lookup_field its so frustrating. I've read those drf docs also saw somewhere DRF encourages users to use .get_object() but even that didnt do for me. But thanks for answer. Ill try to dig in more